# Using AWS Certificate on Windows EC2 instance With Apache Server and Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I'm trying to use my aws certificate with elastic load balancer on my EC2 instance which has Apache. I followed this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html#configure-health-check to create my classic load balancer.After that creation everything looks right in my load balancer console . But when i try to browse my website with https instead of http chrome says connection is not secure. When i look inside of certificate from browser i see that certificate published by **localhost**.
So is there any additional configuration that i have to do like in my httpd-ssl.conf file or something else? By the way all this services are in the same region.(Frankfurt)

Comment: Are you using the ELB to server the Certificate? Do you have HTTPS pointed at your Apache Port 80 or 443? Or both?   One of the benefits of using an ELB is turning off SSl on your appache config and letting ELB do all the SSL work. I would make your appache server run on port 80. Then porting port 443 on the ELB at port 80 on your EC2 instance(s). Load your cert in the AWS Cert Manager and configure ELB to use it.

Comment: Aws says there is only two way to use aws certs. These are ELB and Cloudfront.Because of the region problems i chose ELB.Actually i don't know the meaning of the "HTTPS pointed on Apache" but it's listening 80 and 443. And i've already config my ELB's listener 443 (HTTPS) to 80 (HTTP) and one more listener with 80 (HTTP) to 80 (HTTP). So i can not understand where did i mistake?

Comment: OK that does sound correct.  Want to share screenshots of your ELB config or aws CLI output?  Is DNS pointed at your EC2 instance or your ELB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks George!!! Route DNS to ELB is the key point. Since you sent that comment i had been working on it. Now i got it! Here is the link of routing DNS to ELB;
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html